# How can I unpublish old apps without having to update them

Tags: android, google-play

I got some old apps that I published before google made "Short description" and "Feature Graphic" compulsory. Now I am trying to unpublished them, I can't see an option to do that. It seems I need to add a short description and feature text then update, then unpublish. Is this right, or is it possible to unpublish without having to do this because I have many apps and Don't want to do this for each one?

edit: this is not a duplicate of the question linked because I simply want to unpublish the app, not 'permenantly delete it' or reuse the package name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **publish** and **unpublished** buttons are right next to each other:

Simply click "Unpublish app" to Unpublished your app.

[image]

You can simply "Unpublished" your app without updating it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that link it hidden with that colour. The problem still persists though it is complaining about errors in the form so I guess I have to supply a feature graphic and short text before I can unpublish. Crazy

Comment: @code578841441 Maybe try reporting it to Google Play. I have tried reporting and I never really get any feedback. Do you need help with anything else?

Comment: This doesn't work when short desc and promo pic are missing. It says "The application could not be saved. Please check the form for errors."